# How to know in magento 2, command to get cache information?

Tags: magento2, cache

What command would we use to get the cache status that is to know which caches are enabled or disabled in Magento 2?

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 2 from your console you can run the following command to get the status of your Magento cache

```
php bin/magento cache:status
```

The abbreviation is as follows

```
php bin/magento c:sta
```